Missing news for specific websites on GDELT
I am new to using GDELT and was trying to explore the data with some google big queries I noticed that it was missing some news for specific websites when i queried them. Is this usual? I am planning to use it and can't afford missing news.
I tried this query:
SELECT 
    DATE,
    SourceCommonName,
    DocumentIdentifier as URL
FROM 
    `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`
WHERE 
    _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP("2024-04-26") AND
    (DocumentIdentifier LIKE '%webrazzi%')

And it was missing 2 news.
